# Databricks ODBC Driver fails if number of rows are exceeding the limit

Tags: python, odbc, databricks

After installing Databricks ODBC Driver and configuring from https://www.databricks.com/spark/odbc-drivers-download, it can fetch a maximum of 16,000 records but fails if the record count is 16,000 or more.

Looks like this is related to the cloud fetch architecture mentioned at  https://www.databricks.com/blog/2021/08/11/how-we-achieved-high-bandwidth-connectivity-with-bi-tools.html

I am looking for a workaround or option to bypass this and use the default architecture when the number of records is more than 16,000. Is there any known parameter for this?

Answer (score 0):

Add following parameter to the connection string that uses default architecture to fix the issue.
EnableQueryResultDownload="0"

Note: 16,000 row limit is different for different tables. I have a new table where the limit is 9,532 rows.